# MySql/MariaDB truncates a part of integer when saving a data and appends with zeros at the end

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a table that contains a column ***tos_id*** which is of data type ***bigint(20)*** When saving a sample like below from my PHP/MySql app, I see following data:

**tos_id** in HTTP Network tab: ***9112884569788786***

Actual inserted **tos_id** value in MySql table column: ***9112884569788700***

**Another sample:**

tos_id in Network tab: 6875884568568743

Inserted tos_id in MySql table column: 6875884568568000

I researched numerous forumns and posts that said for saving a large integer like the one that contains 25 or 30 digits in length, bigint(20) is the most preferred. I'm confused if I'm doing something wrong or I should use it some other way, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I saw this issue when saving trying to [save real-time time-on-site](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite) data for analytics in our web apps.

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a683db7f8651a784ca8a9e1ffcc418c3 Your values have 16 digits and must be stored completely without shown issue. Maybe this is your client/framework/etc. "service"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "numerous forumns and posts" are wrong.  If you want to store 30 digits without truncating the data, you need to use `decimal(30,0)`.

`bigint(20)` specifies the bigint type, and a display width of 20.  The display width has no effect on the data, and specifying it is deprecated in recent versions of MySQL.  A bigint, whatever display width you specify, can store numbers -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, so any 18 digit number or most 19 digit numbers.  There are no integer types in mysql that allow 20 or more digits to be stored without trunctation.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=48d4c06fa654768017f3bd1cc3e5a62d)

Comment: Also, PHP operates with 64 bit signed integers, so OP must use strings for large numbers or use an arbitrary precision libs, which do the same.

Comment: That's helpful. But can you explain what's the use of **bigint** with (20) as suggested in other SO posts. Just curious to know what it does.

Comment: bigint is x64 integer, it can keep numbers up to 2^64 when unsigned or twice less when signed

Comment: (20) means that MySQL driver will display no more than 20 first digits of the origin value, the rest you can find in MySQL manuals, it's faster than create a question here

Comment: that's good point, but I thought that a numeric value that is of length < 18 or < 20 like "9112884569788786" should be covered within this bigInt(20) but sadly it doesn't and other forums then keep suggesting on it without knowing its limitations.

Comment: 9112884569788786 should be fine to store as a bigint; what are you trying that it isn't?

Comment: @webblover, you should invest some time into C, C types and C structures

Comment: @ysth yes, you are correct but as you saw in OP, the actual inserted value is always wrong appended with numerous zeros at the end, that's why I opened this Post as well for gaining some knowledge on it.

Comment: @webblover, you must show your column definition and your MySQL INSERT code to let others find your mistake.

Comment: ah, I didn't see that you were using a shorter number in the question.  it seems like you have two problems, one with numbers greater than a bigint can store (solved by using a decimal type), and one with your php code not handling large bigint values correctly.  I don't know enough about the php mysql clients to know if that will be a problem with a decimal type too.

Comment: @ysth, all MySQL drivers in PHP handle DECIMAL values properly, unless a developer tries to cast a string to integer somewhere. I'm sure he also declared his BIGINT as BIGINT(13) or something similar.

Comment: I used this sample as is [https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite/backend/index.html#PHP](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite/backend/index.html#PHP) but not sure. This discussion has been very much helpful for all others as well new to the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @webblover, you must show _your_ current code and table/column definition.